# Import failed - Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, import

I have two JavaScript files, and I'm trying to import and use the first one in the second file. The code I'm trying to import is the following:

```
let someFunction = function ( elem ) {
    // some function stuff
};
```

And I'm trying to import it and use it in another file like this:

```
import '../utilities/functions';

const App = App || {};

App.someComponent = () => {
    // call the someFunction function here
}

App.someComponent();
```

However, I get an error in `console.log` which says `Uncaught ReferenceError: someFunction is not defined`. The path to the file is correct, but I still can't use the function. Any advice on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you exporting `someFunction` from `utilities/functions`? Also, you should import it with the appropriate name, e.g. `import { someFunction } from '../utilities/functions';`

Comment: Are you `export`-ing it?

Comment: How are you importing/exporting though? Babel, requirejs, webpack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this, in first file:

```
const someFunction = function ( elem ) {
// some function stuff
};

export default someFunction ;
```

second file:

```
import someFunction from '../utilities/functions';
```